# Xcode: Set a button background image to change everytime the button is pressed

Tags: ios, image, button

I'm new to Xcode and programming and I am not sure how to set the `image` of the `UIButton` to change every time it is tapped. For example, if it was a clock the button would start at the 12 o clock position and if the button was tapped it would change the image to the 1 0 clock position and so on.

I have this method in my .h

```
 -(IBAction)Hexa1Button:(id)sender;
```

and I am kinda stuck there.

Comment: `[Button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this sample logic .This may be useful for you.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
            isCount = 0; // int value.
          UIImage * image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SampleImage1.png"];
            UIImage * image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SampleImage2.png"];
            UIImage * image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SampleImage3.png"];
            UIImage * image4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SampleImage4..png"];
            UIImage * image5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SampleImage5.png"];
            UIImage * image6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SampleImage6.png"];
            UIImage * image7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SampleImage7.png"];
            UIImage * image8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SampleImage8.png"];
            UIImage * image9 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SampleImage9.jpg"];
            imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:image1,image2,image3,image4,image5,image6,image7,image8,image9, nil];

        }   
     -(IBAction)Hexa1Button:(id)sender{
      if( isCount < [imagesArray count]){ 
      [Hexa1Button setBackgroundImage:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:isCount] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     isCount ++;
          }  
     }
```

Comment: This code will crash on the 11th tap of the button.

Comment: i am provide you sample code .......you can change limit level according to your application purpose.

Comment: Sorry about that vaguely worded question, i wasnt thinking straight lol.
So i have this button and i want it to change an image in the uiimageview to the next image in a 6 image sequence every time the button is clicked, i set the uiimageview to random to any of the images when the page is loaded up using -(void)viewDidLoad Hexa1Type = arc4random() %6; in my .m .